# Explanation of JavaScript Decimal Rounding example at MDN?

Tags: javascript, rounding, tostring

I'm learning JavaScript, and I've heard that there can be issues among different browsers when using JavaScript's Math.round() and .toFixed() methods.  After researching on this website, the solution I've with the seen with least criticisms are the Decimal Rounding method as illustrated [at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

Looking over the code, I'm confused by this part:

```
function decimalAdjust(type, value, exp) {
  // If the exp is undefined or zero...
  if (typeof exp === 'undefined' || +exp === 0) {
    return Math[type](value);
  }
  value = +value;
  exp = +exp;
  // If the value is not a number or the exp is not an integer...
  if (isNaN(value) || !(typeof exp === 'number' && exp % 1 === 0)) {
    return NaN;
  }
  // Shift
  value = value.toString().split('e');
  value = Math[type](+(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] - exp) : -exp)));
  // Shift back
  value = value.toString().split('e');
  return +(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] + exp) : exp));
}
```

Specifically, I'm confused by the line "**value = value.toString().split('e');**", appearing about five lines from the bottom.

From what I gather, JavaScript is changing "value" to text, then splitting it at 'e'.  Where is this 'e' coming from?  Whenever I use the "toString()" method on a float such as 11.111, I get "11.111".  Is the 'e' somehow implied?  Is it stored somewhere along with the string?  Do they really mean "toExponential()"?

Thanks in advance for any input, and I apologize if this is a stupid question.  If anyone has a more reliable solution, please feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't tried the `toString` method on `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.11`? See [ES5, section 9.8.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8.1), steps 9 and 10: "Return the String consisting of the most significant digit of the decimal representation of s, followed by a decimal point ‘.’, followed by the remaining k−1 digits of the decimal representation of s, followed by the lowercase character ‘`e`’..."

Comment: The `e` is used to represent huge numbers in scientific notation: `aaaebbb` is `aaa * 10 ^ (bbb)`.

Comment: I'm aware that it spits out an 'e' if you put in a large number (I don't know how large it has to be exactly)...but what if you wanted to round a relatively small number?  Such as 1.1111, rounded to the hundredths place?  Wouldn't this method be useless for anything beyond that breaking point where the toString() method starts using 'e'?

Comment: After reading apsillers' comment and exploring the link, along with looking at meskobalazs' answer below, I've figured it out.  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `e` is the exponential symbol in scientific notation, you get it in `toString()` when the number is really big (or small).

For example `0.0000000000001` yields `1e-13`.

As for the other part of your question:

The method is applicable also when there is no exponential part. In this case the `split` function returns a one length array, so `value[1]` becomes `undefined` which is falsy. In this case, we basically ignore it.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but that still begs the question--what if you want to use decimal rounding on a smaller number (i.e., less digits)?  Is it only applicable when the toString() method finds it necessary to use 'e' to express the number?  Thanks :)

Comment: Alright, I think I got it now.  I didn't recognize that the ".split('e')" was a kind of filter for larger expressions.  Thanks again--can't vote you up yet, but I've accepted your answer :)